# Write-off and replenishment of funds for the object Customer in Stripe

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

Good afternoon. Interested in a question related to the integration of Stripe.

The business task is as follows: We have products in which you can invest your money (P1), we also have a system of rewards for users (P2, P3). The creator of the project (P0) also receives some kind of reward.

Question:

1. How to create a list of users so that they can deposit money and we can reward them with rewards in the future. I know about such objects in the Strip as Session Hescote (for debiting funds from the card) and Payout (for crediting to a bank account). But the Checkout object is created for the Customer, and Payut for the Account Connect. How to be?
2. Is it possible to create an Account with the Cyst type, without filling in the bank details in detail. Let's say only the card number and that's it?

Can someone share their solution? The main task is to realize investment in the project, as well as encouraging users (crediting money to the client's card).

Comment: A typo in the second paragraph (Cyst), an account with the type (Custom)

Comment: So EDIT your question, you can do that any number of time

Comment: To charge a connected account, you can go here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits#charging-a-connected-account. A transfer would be how you can credit the connect account. To have an active custom account, you'll have to provide bank information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe is, in general, a ONE-WAY payment processor - FROM "Customers who make payments via various methods" TO "Business Accounts that take payments" - either the Platform, or connected Accounts.  Stripe does NOT make payments or transfers to "Customers", and does NOT transfer funds between Connected Accounts.

There is a (far more complex) "Banking as a Service" as well...

Their ToS (Terms of Service) also explicitly says they generally *do not* support crowd-funding and equity-funding services...

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found the solution, thanks for the help everyone.

I'm attaching a flow below that works for me.

Creation of a sub account in the Stripe system.
Each system user (project creator, investor, ambassador) will be created in the Stripe system as a separate user through the functionality (https://stripe.com/docs/connect).

Verification and data filling.
Each user will need to fill out their profile in Stripe for the system to work correctly. The data entry form is provided by Stripe. (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connect-onboarding)

Investment. The money goes to the main account.
To invest in a product, you need to create a Checkout widget, this functionality is provided by Stripe. It is required to specify information about the product and set a price, and then ask the user of our system (the Investor) to enter the bank card details. (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout)

The distribution of funds received between the main account and under the account.
Once funds are deposited into Stripe's account, the funds need to be distributed among customers.
To distribute funds, you need to use (https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers)

Withdrawal of funds to the user's account.
After there is money on the client's account, you can withdraw it through the functionality (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts)